# Standard PHP or PHP framework for better speed?

Tags: php, mysql

We want to make a large online users and database based website with PHP. Our database will be MySQL. PHP has many ready frameworks already. Time is not problem and we have enough time for project. So I want to learn about the code core.

Can standard PHP code which we learn from php.net give better speed compared to PHP frameworks? Or we must use any framework like Symfony2, Zend or Codeigniter?

Comment: The fastest code to execute is that which does not exist.

Comment: That depends on your level of skill and what it is suppossed to do. If you have a good understanding of how to program efficiently, that might be the better choice.  
The con is that you will have to make everything yourself.

However, a good framework has been tested, debugged, improved and might be fast to setup, because a lot has been premade. A framework has a lot of overhead though, so for small projects it might be a bad thing.

Comment: Enough time for the project? Consider stepping away from PHP/MySQL.

Comment: it depends on how simple we code it without adding unneccessary complexity

Comment: Such frameworks will not get you a better performing site. They are about ease and speed of development. That comes with a (in some cases very steep) learning curve. Learning how to use a framework might be too much of an effort if you only intend to use it for one project. On the other hand it forces you to work along the lines of decent programming concepts which might justify the overhead of learning the framework. Basically it's up to you. Evaluate what kind of programmer you are.

Comment: If your database will be really large choosing a better performing database than MySQL might be better. I suggest you look into PostgreSQL then.

Comment: Phalcon, http://phalconphp.com/,  marketed as The fastest PHP Framework. "Phalcon is a web framework implemented as a C extension offering high performance and lower resource consumption."

Comment: Remember that speed of execution isn't everything. Speed of development, availability of skills, and TCO of the resulting stack are important too.

Comment: I don't know what you think a framework is but, save for very specific options like [Phalcon](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon), they're normally written in PHP. Asking if framework code plus custom code can be faster that only custom code is a weird question. It's like asking if a truck can be faster than a car; it *can* be faster, if the truck is carefully tuned for speed and you compare it with a crappy car. But companies don't buy trucks seeking speed, they buy them because they need to move big loads across the country.

Comment: While Phalcon might sound interesting it is really not unless you have your own webserver. Hosted services rarely allow this framework.

Comment: Hmm, +4 is slightly eyebrow-raising for an un-researched and off-topic question, surely?